# Connection refused! Is selenium server started?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, nightwatch.js

I am using Jenkins to run selenium nightwatch tests.

When I run the tests, I get the following error:

```
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
```

I have the following configuration in my nightwatch.json file:

```
"selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar",
        "log_path": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "lib/chromedriver",
            "webdriver.ie.driver": "lib/IEDriverServer_x64_2.52.2.exe",
            "trustAllSSLCertificates": true
        }
```

I'm guessing Jenkins is trying to connect to a PORT but is unable to do so. Can someone please help?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the browserName is correct.

```
"desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true
}
```

browserName: "internet explorer" and not "ie"
also your are missing the ".exe" in webdriver.chrome.driver